# what is alternative to MongoCursor::hasNext in new mongodb driver MongoDB\Driver\Cursor?

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

New php mongodb driver has removed hasNext method.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-cursor.php

```
MongoDB\Driver\Cursor implements Traversable {

/* Methods */
    final private __construct ( void )
    final public MongoDB\Driver\CursorId getId ( void )
    final public MongoDB\Driver\Server getServer ( void )
    final public bool isDead ( void )
    final public void setTypeMap ( array $typemap )
    final public array toArray ( void )
}
```

We are trying to upgrade mongodb to latest version 3.2 and mongodb php driver 1.1. We have used hasNext at some places in code which we need to refactor. I tried using this https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-cursor.php#118824

```
class MongodbCursor
{
    public static function hasNext(\MongoDB\Driver\Cursor $cursor)
    {
        $it = new \IteratorIterator($cursor);
        $it->rewind();
        return $it->valid();
    }
}
```

e.g.

```
 $cursor = some mongo query to get cursor

if (!MongodbCursor::hasNext($cursor)){

  //  since there is no data in above cursor, another query to get new cursor
  $cursor = 

}

foreach ($cursor as $item) {

}
```

It gives below error,

```
Cursors cannot yield multiple iterators
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `IteratorIterator` method to check whether the cursor is empty. 
For example:

```
$cursor = $collection->find(array('key'=> 'value'));
$it = new IteratorIterator($cursor);
$it->rewind();

if (!$it->current()){
    // Cursor is empty
    $cursor = $collection->find(array('anotherKey'=> 'anotherValue'));
    $it = new IteratorIterator($cursor);
    $it->rewind();
}
// Iterator all docs
while ($doc = $it->current()) {
    // Do something
    $it->next();
}
```

See also [MongoDB PHP Library CRUD Tutorials](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/master/tutorial/)

Comment: $cursor->toArray() is it efficient ? It will fetch all documents and convert to array ?

Comment: Not sure why the downvote. The answer was edited a long time ago not to use toArray.